# `\setcounter` in latex block to typeset matrices with more than 10 columns

Tags: org-mode, latex

I typesetting a matrix with 12 columns in a latex block in org-mode and discovered I couldn't do it by default. Reading this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95162/how-to-create-a-matrix-with-20-columns-in-latex) on the `TeX` stack exchange site made me think that I could just place `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}` as the first command in the block. This didn't work. However, it does export correctly. Is there a way to place this option in my `init.el` so I don't have to remember this every time?

```
 #+BEGIN_LATEX
  \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
  \begin{equation*}
  \mathbf{X} = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation*}
  #+END_LATEX
```

Comment: Can you also post the generated LaTeX code? Maybe `begin_latex` macro generates an environment where this command can't be used? What is the exact error you are getting? (It will appear in the `*Org PDF ... output* buffer (can't remember the exact name).

Comment: Your example works on my system with org `v8.2` and `v8.3beta` and Texlive 2014.

Comment: BTW: You can also write the matrix as (eval it): `(insert "\n#+LATEX_HEADER: \\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}\n#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment pmatrix :mode math :math-prefix \\mathbf{X}=\n | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |\n | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |\n | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |\n | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |\n | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |\n | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |\n | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |\n | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |")`

Comment: I discovered that it does work in the outputted PDF includes the matrix, the live preview feature doesn't know about it.